# Login Dialog with caliburn micro

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I want to show a login dialogbox before showing the main window. I call this dialogbox inside the OnInitialize of the main viewmodel. I got an InvalidOperationException with "Cannot set Owner property to a Window that has not been shown previously."

So, how to show a dialogbox before any other window?

The dialogbox is declared as < Window >

Answer (score 1):

I put the call to the login dialog into the OnViewLoaded of the rootview and the exception is gone. The rootview is already shown together with the login dialog.

Answer (score -3):

Change your `App.xaml`'s `StartupUri` to be your dialog window. And when login is successful, you then open the main window.

Comment: You should not use the StartupUri in Caliburn Micro, instead you should be using the Bootstrapper.

Comment: The login dialog is not my root view, so I cannot define the login dialog as my root view in the bootstrapper.